# Make it easier to call a custom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have written a plugin with the following "signature":

```
jQuery.fn.attach = function(element, settings, duration, options, callback) {
```

Here `element` is a jQuery object, `settings` are my custom settings for my plugin and `duration`, `options` and `callback` are all parameters that I use in jQuery's animate, like this:

```
someObject.animate({ someCSS }, duration, options, callback);
```

Now, my question is: Is it possible to make this function easier to call? For instance, right now, to get everything to work as I expect... I have to include all parameters and set the parameters that I don't use to `null`:

```
$(this).attach($('#e1-blue'), null, 3000, null, function() { alert('done'); });
```

It would be nice to **also** be able to call this as:

```
$(this).attach($('#e1-blue'), 3000, function() { alert('done'); });
```

and as this (ofc)...

```
$(this).attach($('#e1-blue'), 3000);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I can think of is re-ordering the parameters such that the most commonly used ones come first. So if you change the function to:

```
jQuery.fn.attach = function(element, duration, callback, settings, options) {
```

then you can make everything (except probably the first parameter) optional by putting default values into the function body. Such as:

```
if(!duration)
   duration = 3000;
```

Then

```
$(this).attach($('#e1-blue'), 3000, function() { alert('done'); });
```

and

```
$(this).attach($('#e1-blue'), 3000);
```

would both be valid, with the other values automatically populated with `null`.

Strictly speaking, you could check for parameter types inside the function e.g. if the second paramter is an integer then it's the `duration`, if it's a function it's `callback`, if it's an object it's `settings`, but I don't think people who have to follow your code later will thank you for it. It could also make the function difficult to extend later down the line if e.g. a second integer parameter was required.

Answer (score 2):

I setup a defaults object, and accept only one argument in the plugin function

```
  $.fn.myPlugin=function(opt){
    var o=$.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, opt||{});
  };
  $.fn.myPlugin.defaults={
    element: null,
    settings: null,
    options: null,
    callback: null,
    duration: 250
  };
```

Instantiate the plugin

```
$('#myElement').myPlugin({element: $('#el-blue'), duration: 2000})
```

If you're passing something every time, you could make the options object the second argument.

```
  $.fn.myPlugin=function(element, opt){
   return this.each(function(){
    var o=$.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, opt||{});
    //do some stuff
    if (o.callback) {
     o.callback.call(this, o);
    }
   });
  };

$('#myElement').myPlugin($('#el-blue'), {duration: 3000, callback: function(){}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at method signatures to see how people handle optional arguments.  For instance, look at http://gist.github.com/277432#LID5445 to see the setup behind jQuery.speed, which is what jQuery.animate uses - http://gist.github.com/277432#LID5445.

Regardless, you'd just want to look at the type of your arguments to see whether or not people passed them in.